# Laravel requires the Mcrypt PHP extension. Not working for cron jobs

Tags: php, cron, laravel, laravel-4, mcrypt

So I am plagued with this issue like many others have been but with no solution.

**The Issue**: commands issued by a cron task do not run and give the message: `Laravel requires the Mcrypt PHP extension.`

I can run commands through `artisan` and they work fine. I am using MAMP on OSX 10.8.

I've quadrupal checked my `.bash_profile` to ensure the correct PATH is set which is: `export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/bin:$PATH`. Confirmed by `which php` in terminal. `php -v` confirms PHP 5.4.4 is being used. `php -i` confirms mcrypt extension is installed and enabled. Even adding `die(phpversion().PHP_EOL);` to `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/start.php` it's confirmed that it's using the correct version.

So I'm stumped. I don't know why cronjobs aren't recognizing either the correct PHP version or that the mcrypt extension is installed. What can I try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't rely on PATH being set for cronjob through .bash_profile (it's a shell feature and cronjobs are not running through a shell), you should rather use something like

```
* * * * * /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/bin/php-something? /path/to/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/start.php
```

A test could be something like this:

```
# /tmp/test.php
<?php file_put_contents('/tmp/a_test', `id`."\n".var_export($_ENV, true)."\n".var_export(extension_loaded('mcrypt'), true));
# in crontab
* * * * * /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/bin/php-something? /tmp/test.php
```

Run `php /tmp/test.php` one time manually to spot the differences between you running the script, and cron; and always try to use absolute paths in crontab (in this case to your php binary).

Comment: So, essentially you are saying that best practice should be to set the absolute path in a cron command? I didn't know that. Isn't there a way to tell the version of php running CLI commands to use the same version as my PATH?

Comment: @JaredEitnier: you could do `* * * * * . /home/your_user/.bash_profile && php /path/to/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/start.php`(more info about . or "source" here: http://superuser.com/questions/46139/what-does-source-do)

Comment: I'll stick to absolute path instead :) Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

This is probably a PHP problem, look at the code reponsible for that message:

```
if ( ! extension_loaded('mcrypt'))
{
    die('Laravel requires the Mcrypt PHP extension.'.PHP_EOL);

    exit(1);
}
```

Test your php on the command line running:

```
php -r 'echo PHP_EOL . (extension_loaded("mcrypt") ? "loaded" : "not loaded") . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;'
```

MCrypt is installed and available to php? Test it running:

```
php -i | grep  mcrypt
```

It must show you at least:

```
mcrypt support => enabled
mcrypt_filter support => enabled
```

EDIT:

Another possibility is cron running a different php (php, php-cli, php-cgi) and when you explicitly selected the right one it worked. Take a look at all your php.ini files to see if mcrypt is enabled in all of them.

Comment: returns `loaded` & both `mcrypt support` & `mcrypt_filter` are enabled

Comment: Ok, so I just set the php path explicitly to MAMP's PHP path in my crontab command. Previously I was just using `* * * * * php /path/to/my/script.php`. It works now but I don't want to have to explicitly set the path. Can I fix that?