# Mcrypt PHP extension installation doesn't work

Tags: laravel, xampp

I am trying to install laravel via composer ( http://laravel.com/docs/quick#installation ) and I got stuck at the point where it requires Mcrypt extension

```
Mcrypt PHP extension required.
```

I installed Mcrypt extension using brew. But still it throws the same requirement error. 
I also tried changing the path as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19250415/laravel-requires-the-mcrypt-php-extension-not-working-for-cron-jobs) but my which php doesn't show anything other than

```
/usr/bin/php
```

Am I doing something wrong with assigning path at ~/.bash_profile? why is "which php" output still the same. and why is mcrypt installation not working on laravel workout?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Laravel requires the Mcrypt PHP extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16830405/laravel-requires-the-mcrypt-php-extension)

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21762604/mcrypt-not-detected-with-laravel-installation?rq=1 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16830405/laravel-requires-the-mcrypt-php-extension?rq=1 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I was fed up off all other solutions which weren't working, so finally downloading and compiling php from source itself worked.

So here's what I did:

1. Download php from official [site](http://www.php.net/downloads.php)
2. Follow following instructions

   ```
   cd to/extracted/php/folder
   cd /ext/mycript
   phpize
   ./configure
   make
   make test
   sudo make install
   ```

Add `extension=mcrypt.so` to `/etc/php.ini` file.
Now restart the server

```
sudo apachectl restart
```

You are good to go, Cheers! :)

Answer (score 0):

What command did you use to install mcrypt? It is possible that you try to install the mcrypt extension for the wrong php version.

Try debugging the situation with

```
php -v
```

and

```
ls -al /usr/bin/php
```

There is a different install recipe for version 5.5 and 5.4 of PHP.

```
brew install php54-mcrypt
brew install php55-mcrypt
```

Comment: I used brew install php54-mcrypt
since php -v gives 
PHP 5.4.24

Comment: Did the brew installation succeed?

Comment: yes it did succeed. How do I check if it succeed or not?

Comment: And what does `php -r "phpinfo();" | grep mcrypt` say?

Comment: outputs nothing. but when I give brew install command again it says "Warning: php54-mcrypt-5.4.27 already installed"

Comment: Now it's time to use `ls -al` to find out which version is run when you execute `php` without any params. `ls -al /usr/bin/php` and follow the symlinks.

Comment: Here is the output: -rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  10001104 Feb 18 05:08 /usr/bin/php. btw, how do I follow symlinks?

Comment: It seems like /usr/bin/php is not a symlink. That's odd.